# GPS location not showing by Toast

Tags: android, location, return, toast

The toast message in the code below doesn't seem to show and I can't determine why. Is there an error I missed?

`MyCurrentLocation` is the activity name

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(MyCurrentLocation.this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){

    try{
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        List <Address> addr = gc.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude(),1);
        String results = "";
        if (addr.size() > 0){
        results += addr.get(0).getCountryName();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),results,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } catch(Exception e){

     }
```

Comment: It didn't work for me either on Emulator. It works on Device.Did you try testing on device?

Comment: Have you tried posting the GPS information to Logcat?

Comment: @AndersMetnik the internet permission? yes there is in the androidmanifest file

Comment: @Abhilasha perhaps i should test on the device thanks

Comment: @ShiXuan: Working on similar app.On device it works like a charm. I have no clue what's wrong with emulator.On device; Tap any location, it gives address info!! I have it on my device running right now.

Comment: @Abhilasha can i inquire something? mine work on the phone however the toast keep appearing

Comment: @ShiXuan GeoCoder api dont work on emulator, test on device it will. Good point Abhilasha

Comment: In my `OverLay` class , I have oeverridden `onTouchEvent()` and there I have displayed using `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. Now since you have called it `onLocationChanged()` I am not very sure why it is constantly displayed. Try making the `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT`.

Comment: Test in real device because emulator does not support GPS....

Answer (score 0):

Pls make sure you have set correct permissions in your Android manifest file.

The GPS doesn't work correctly in Android 2.x simulator correctly. If possible try with Android 4.0.

Also the best option is to test it with devices, GPS also doesn't work correctly from enclosed locations.

You can follow the below link -
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```